# preg_grep outputting partial match

Tags: php, preg-grep

So I'm currently using preg_grep to find lines containing string, but if a line contains special chars such as " - . @ " I can simply type 1 letter that is within that line and it will output as a match.. example of line

```
example@users.com
```

search request

```
ex
```

and it will output

```
example@users.com
```

but it should only output " example@users.com " if search request matches " example@users.com " this problem only occurs on lines using special chars, for example

if i search " example " on a line that contains

```
example123
```

it will respond

```
not found
```

but if i search the exact string " example123 "

it will of course output as it suppose too

```
example123
```

so the issue seems to lay with lines containing special characters..

my current usage of grep is,

```
    if(trim($query) == ''){
        $file = (preg_grep("/(^\$query*$)/", $file));
    }else{
        $file = (preg_grep("/\b$query\b/i", $file));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = [
    'example@users.com',
    'example',
    'example123',
    'ex',
    'ex123',
];
$q = 'ex';
$out = preg_grep("/^$q(?:.*[-.@]|$)/", $in);
print_r($out);
```

**Explanation**

```
^           : begining of line
$q          : the query value
(?:         : start non capture group
    .*      : 0 or more any character
    [-.@]   : a "special character", you could add all you want
  |         : OR
    $       : end of line
)           : end group
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => example@users.com
    [3] => ex
)
```

---

**Edit, according to comment:**

You have to use `preg_replace`:

```
$in = [
    'example@users.com',
    'example',
    'example123',
    'ex',
    'ex123',
];
$q = 'ex';
$out = preg_replace("/^($q).*$/", "$1", preg_grep("/^$q(?:.*[.@-]|$)/", $in));
print_r($out);
```

**Ooutput:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ex
    [3] => ex
)
```

Comment: still outputs everything containing " ex " i need exact match to be precise, so if q="ex" and line is " example " output should be nothing, if q="example" then output should be " example "

Comment: well if it contains @, ., - or other special chars.. the output shouldn't contain " example@users.com " due to q="ex" it should only output " ex "

Comment: @user3255841: I don't get your first comment, this is exactly what my script is doing, it outputs `ex` if line is `ex` ans nothing if line is `ex123` or `example`. For the oher comment, pleasde, edit your question and add test cases with extract of input file, some example of queries and expected result.

Comment: Okay your $q was " ex " and yourput was " ex " but also " example@users.com ", it shouldn't be outputting " example@users.com " because $q didn't = " example@users.com "